# Is jni supported in roscpp indigo?

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing a node in C++ which communicates with Java code. I think the most elegant way to do this is by using JNI.
Is jni supported in roscpp indego? Can anyone point me to a tutorial or example?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226202/is-jni-supported-in-roscpp-indigo?/) by [Yael Green](https://answers.ros.org/users/25899/yael-green/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-10**:
Can you be a bit more specific? In what way do you think that `roscpp` should 'support jni'? I'd expect that if a typical C/C++ program can call into Java through JNI, a ROS node should be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

JNI is supported since my code is writen in C++. To get it to work I added to the CMakeLists:

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-L /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/jre/lib/amd64/server/ -I /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/include/ -I /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/include/linux/ -ljvm -std=c++0x")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/g++")
set(JAVA_COMPILE "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_79/bin")

find_package(Java REQUIRED)
find_package(JNI REQUIRED)

if (JNI_FOUND)
message (STATUS "JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS=${JNI_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message (STATUS "JNI_LIBRARIES=${JNI_LIBRARIES}")
endif()

include(UseJava)

---

Originally posted by [Yael Green](https://answers.ros.org/users/25899/yael-green/) with karma: 16 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0